# Encoding categorical data with pre-determined dictionary

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-engineering, encoding, categorical-encoding

in case feature encoding, if I'd like to encode my values based on my pre-determined dictionary, how do I do that?

For instance, say, I've values as `[Red, Green, and Blue]` and I want to encode them as `[-1,0,1]`  -1 for red, 0 for Green, 1 for Blue... I'll apply it to my feature. I believe I can do it by mapping, apply method, not sure. But is there any better way to do that?

````
Column     expectedEncoding
Red             -1
Red             -1
Blue             1
Green            0
Red             -1
Blue             1

```
````

Comment: What technology are you using? What library?

Comment: sklearn, pandas, numpy etc.

Comment: Then your best approach is just using `df[col].map(mapping)` where `col` is the name of the column to be encoded and `mapping` is a dictionary with the values

Comment: Alright, I thought there might be another way for that. Well then, can I do it for different columns with different dictionaries at once?

Comment: I'll be answering this in a post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a pandas DataFrame and one mapping per column, with all mappings stored in a 2-level dict where the keys of the first level correspond to the columns in the dataframe and the keys of the second level correspond to the categories:

```
{'fruit': {'banana': -1, 'apple': 1}, 'color': {'yellow': -1, 'red': 1}}
```

Then, you can do the following:

```py
encoded_data = data.apply(lambda col: col.map(mappings[col.name]))
```

[EDIT] if have columns for which you don't have a mapping, you can do one of the following:

```py
data.update(data[list(mappings)].apply(lambda col: col.map(mappings[col.name])))
```

or if you want it in a new dataframe (eg to keep the dataframe with the original values):

```py
encoded_data = data.copy()
encoded_data.update(data[list(mappings)].apply(lambda col: col.map(mappings[col.name])))
```

Comment: There is key error if the column name is not in the dict

Comment: yes this is expected. You can filter the columns first if you want to avoid this

Comment: Can you please also show me how to do that?

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.replace({'fruit': {'banana': -1, 'apple': 1}, 'color': {'yellow': -1, 'red': 1}},inplace=True)
```

given that `'fruit'` and `'color'` are columns in your data-frame.

Comment: This `.replace(dic)` seems to be shorter than `.apply(lambda col: col.map(mappings[col.name]))`